# How can I use a named range that contains an array constant within application.worksheetfunction.networkdays()?

Tags: excel, vba

When using Application.WorksheetFunction.NetWorkDays(), how can I reference a named range that contains an array constant of all holidays?

```vb
ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(startDate, endDate, namedRangeGoesHere)
```

Answer (score 0):

If, for example, your named range is called "holidays" then you need to evaluate the array constant by enclosing the name within square brackets like so:

```vb
ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(startDate, endDate, [holidays])
```

Comment: What's the point of asking something that you know the answer for? Imagine if everybody did that.

Comment: I couldn't find the answer anywhere else on the site, so I posted it for anyone else that's having the same issue and for my own reference.

Comment: Well, please don't. Try a personal notebook to keep your reference.

Comment: @teylyn Stack Overflow explicitly encourages answering your own questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer